# If i try to install MySQL-Server debian will install mariadb-server-10.1

Tags: mysql, shell, mariadb, apt

I need to install MySQL-Server community edition but then i try to install the MySQL-Server it installs mariadb-server-10.1

---

Server logs: https://hastebin.com/erokoboket.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian decided to switch from using Oracle's MySQL to using the MariaDB fork as their default installation.

MariaDB is good software, and so is MySQL. Unfortunately they're diverging a bit in their feature sets.

If you decide you want to install Oracle's MySQL, you need to add its repository to your Debian / Ubuntu package manager.

You can download the file to update your package manager from Oracle here.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Then you add it to your package manager and install MySQL.

```
sudo dpkg -i whatevver-package-name.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Updating the package manager is helpful when it comes time to install updates to MySQL; you can use `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade` to handle it.

There's an explanation on the Oracle web site here. https://mysqlrelease.com/2017/06/debian-9-and-mysql-watch-out/

The explanation must have been written by a marketer charged with keeping market share for Oracle MySQL; it doesn't even mention MariaDB by name. I suppose that kind of attitude is partly the reason the Debian krewe switched.

And, after you install your database software, be sure to set your client software (phpmyadmin and others) so it knows the version you are using.

Comment: I have now this error then i try to add an user with phpmyadmin:  #1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei 'REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_' in Zeile 1

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://dev.mysql.com and down load the .deb file that accesses the MySQL APT repository.  Then follow the directions to install that file and then download mysql